# How to read unnamed JSon Values

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

When parsing the given JSon format with Jackson ObjectMapper, I get the following error:
`Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array`. How can I parse this kind for format?

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

I'm getting this result from an external REST API. The format is not under my control.

Test case to verify the correct parsing:

```
class JSonHelperTest {

  private static final String KLINES = "[\n" +
          "[\n" +
          "  [\n" +
          "    1499040000000,\n" +
          "    \"0.01634790\",\n" +
          "    \"0.80000000\",\n" +
          "    \"0.01575800\",\n" +
          "    \"0.01577100\",\n" +
          "    \"148976.11427815\",\n" +
          "    1499644799999,\n" +
          "    \"2434.19055334\",\n" +
          "    308,\n" +
          "    \"1756.87402397\",\n" +
          "    \"28.46694368\",\n" +
          "    \"17928899.62484339\"\n" +
          "  ]\n" +
          "]\n";
  
  @Test
  public void readKlines() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = JSonHelper.createObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(KLINES);


  }
}
```

Comment: The message suggests that the text you are reading is not valid JSON.

Comment: It is an Object Array, not a valid JSON.

Comment: There was a typo, which I did'nt see. Another opening bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Object Array, not a valid JSON. Is the order/index of the values are always same? I mean High and Low will be always at index 2 and 3? If yes then read them by looping and populating a POJO.

DozerMapping can be useful.
Similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556298/java-convert-list-of-object-array-to-a-pojo?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, the order is always the same. Is there any support in Jackson for manual parsing?

Comment: You can try Dozer mapping. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556298/java-convert-list-of-object-array-to-a-pojo?noredirect=1&lq=1)